# Solution needed for drag / drop UI page builder

Tags: wysiwyg, drag-drop

I am seeking solutions for building a tool that enables non-tech users to build web pages.  This would be a browser-based drag/drop tool similar to how Squarespace, Weebly or Canva allow users to build front end pages and publish them.
(see attached images as reference)

My goal is to find an open source tool similar to https://grapesjs.com/.

Any tech suggestions would be appreciated to enable this type of experience for users.  ~ thank you

[image]

Comment: Please split your question into two section (Use the # syntax to create a section title): 1) What you are looking for and what are your exact requirements. 2) What you intend to build with it. The first section must be understandable without reading the second section. Please edit then ask us to reopen, thanks! :-)